# Which synonyms for “stated” can I use in a legal context?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, legalese

In our law essays we are often required to quote different judges. It becomes really monotonous to use the word "stated" all the time. I have also used "advocated" and "declared". Are there any other words which could suffice in the place of these words?

Example:

> In the GCHQ case Lord Diplock **stated** / **advocated**/ **declared** that illegality, irrationality and procedural impropriety are the three heads of judicial review in the English law.

Comment: Insist, note, claim

Comment: inform, emphasize, point out

Comment: Are you sure that these words aren't invested with rigidly defined senses in the legal register?  There's a (non-definitive) list of what Wiktionary calls 'reporting verbs' but which are arguably more accurately classed as quote verbs [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_reporting_verbs). 'Smile' etc and 'bellow' etc are probably unsuitable, and 'go' and 'be like' definitely so, when writing in the register you indicate.

Comment: How about "said"?

Comment: @lessthanideal it's a legal essay, so your solution is less than ideal.

Comment: Don't judges "find" all the time? (The fiction that judges don't make law, but perceive some sort of Platonic realm in which perfect law already exists.) Doesn't work for the Diplock example, but might for other contexts.

Comment: @Edwin: +1 and <splork> I now have this image of Judge Jeffreys being like, 'You shall be taken to a place of execution and hanged by the neck until you be, like, dead'.

Comment: @DavidPugh Judges 'find' matters of fact and law in the case at hand.

Comment: @StoneyB: And so? OP is quoting judges doing law. They aren't _supposed_ to shoot their mouths off on cases not at hand, are they?

Comment: @DavidPugh But in the example the judge is not announcing a finding but  stating (presumably accurately) a legal principle on which a finding that a particular case was or was not subject to review might be based.

Comment: @StoneyB: I didn't read OP as wanting a word solely for the Diplock example. If he does, of course, my suggestion falls to the ground.

Comment: Tried a thesaurus ?

Comment: In the GCHQ case Lord Diplock asserted that illegality, irrationality and procedural impropriety are the three heads of judicial review in the English law.

Comment: @SajjJhilik Why?  Do legal essays not allow simple words? - Not being snarky, it's a serious question.

Answer (score 3):

Some literatures (French and Farsi have been instanced on this site) applaud and even demand such employment of synonyms; but in English this is deprecated and mocked as ['elegant variation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation).

Moreover, in some disciplines it is regarded as a grave vice to stray from the most neutral term available in introducing a quotation. Any more colorful term, such as *declare*, *insist*, *assert*, improperly imposes your own subjective interpretation on the original, which should be allowed to speak for itself.

*Advocate* in particular should be avoided: a jurist is called upon to pronounce the meaning of law, not to urge a personal opinion.

You may use *rule* or *find* if the jurist's utterance constitutes a binding interpretation of a matter of law or fact in the circumstances at hand, and *affirm* if the jurist upholds a previous ruling; but I advise you to restrict yourself otherwise to *say* or *state* or *write*.